# How to manage web resources from VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2011

Using developer toolkit, I can get the list of the entities into my Visual Studio. However, I'd like to publish too. When I try to do that, I get the error telling me that I can't connect. Is it possible to set up a "mirror" of a CRM-solution in the VS-solution and edit it? Then, when done, just upload all the changes to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about Javascript Web Resources and manage this Web Resources in Visual Studio there isn't any default tool to do that. But exists great tools to help on that:

- [Intellisense](http://crm.vdsnickt.eu/ms-crm-javascript-intellisense-generator/)
- [JS Files](http://jswebresourcemanager.codeplex.com/)
- [Snippetts](http://crm2011snippets.codeplex.com/)
- [Tools in Visual Studio](http://crm2011vstools.codeplex.com/)

If you are using VS 2012 check this [tool](http://webresourcelinker.codeplex.com/).